# Парсинг HTML на Java с Jsoup

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Как можно получить `56,4115` вот отсюда:

```xml
<td class="weak">
   <ins class="rubl">руб.</ins>&nbsp;
   56,4115
</td>
```

Пробовала так, но первого чайлда нет:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://cbr.ru/").get();
Elements tdElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "weak");
tdElements.forEach(tdElement -> {
    Element insElement = tdElement.child(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нет второго вложенного элемента, но есть просто внутренний текст, его и нужно прочесть:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://cbr.ru/").get();
Elements tdElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "weak");
tdElements.forEach(tdElement -> System.out.println(tdElement.ownText()));
```

Answer (score 1):

"Чайлда" и правда нет. Метод [`child(число)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#child-int-) возвращает один дочерний элемент (то есть узел, обрамленный тегами). Зато есть дочерние текстовые узлы, которые можно получить отдельным списком [`textNodes()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes--) или вместе с остальными узлами [`childNodes()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes--)

В случае, когда текстовых узлов больше чем один можно выбрать нужный пользуясь одним из этих методов. Если только один, то пользуйтесь соседним ответом

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал вот так.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://cbr.ru/").get();
            String result = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "weak").select("td").get(0).html();
//если методу get передать значение 1, то получится результат в евро
            result=result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(';')+1);
            System.out.println(result);
```